# Time Tracking on mouse click Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I wanted to make a really simple time tracker that runs in a browser. This is the simplest code I could come up with but I have problems with the click event. The problem is that the whole thing works but it starts on page load and I want it to start on click. Is there anything wrong with the implementation?

Here is my code:

```js
let hours = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let seconds = 0;
function time() {
  setInterval(function () {
    if (seconds < 59) {
      seconds++;
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent =
        hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else if (minutes < 59) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent =
        hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
      hours++;
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent =
        hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", time());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
div {
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#timer {
  min-height: 80px;
  font-size: 4em;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
}
#button {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <h1 id="header">You have been working for:</h1>
      <time id="timer">0:0:0</time>
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Track Time</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can set `<button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="time()">Track Time</button>` onclick on button and remove code `document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", time());
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call the `time` function when you add an event listener. In order to run the `time` function only when the button is clicked, just don't call the `time` function right away:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", time);
```

Comment: This actually works like a charm in a snippet. It must be something wrong with my testing because I can't get it to work in a browser by just opening up the `HTML`  file. I get an error in the console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:23

Comment: @AlexToma that makes sense, because your script is executed before the button is added to the DOM. And because the script can't find the button, it can't attach the event listener. You can go with a classic option and add `defer` here: `<script src="script.js" defer></script>`. In short, the browser will wait until the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired(when HTML is rendered), and then execute your script. And you will have the button available and everything should work :)

Comment: That was exactly what was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use syntax like this because your click function is already triggered at the time adding a event listener.

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    time();
});
```